# Calculate Dates in Ruby

Tags: ruby, date

I have some specific functionality to test with dates.  I've hit a stumbling block.  I need to loop backwards through 14 days from today to generate a date, but weekends must be ignored.

Example:

Today is Monday, going back 1 day would take me to Friday. Going back 2 days would take me to Thursday. We are always two days behind. So, when I then land on a Tuesday, that needs to go to Friday and the Monday to Thursday.  I get it working for 1 week, but the next 7 days it starts the same cycle again.

Here is what I have so far:

```
def date_calc_minus(number)


date = Date.today - number.to_i
  day = date.strftime('%a %e %B %Y').split(' ')[0]


  case
    when day.include?('Sun')
      puts day
      calculated_date = date - 2
    when day.include?('Sat')
      puts day
      calculated_date = date - 2
    else
      puts day
      calculated_date = date - 2
      if calculated_date.strftime('%a %e %B %Y').split(' ')[0].include?('Sun')
        calculated_date = calculated_date - 2
      elsif calculated_date.strftime('%a %e %B %Y').split(' ')[0].include?('Sat')
        calculated_date = calculated_date - 2
      end
  end

  calculated_date.strftime('%a %e %B %Y')
end

start = 1
stop = 14
range = start.to_i.upto(stop.to_i).to_a

range.each_with_index do |number, index|
  puts date_calc_minus(number)
end


#=>



Sun
Fri 27 April 2018
Sat
Thu 26 April 2018
Fri
Wed 25 April 2018
Thu
Tue 24 April 2018
Wed
Mon 23 April 2018
Tue
Fri 20 April 2018
Mon
Thu 19 April 2018
Sun
Fri 20 April 2018
Sat
Thu 19 April 2018
Fri
Wed 18 April 2018
Thu
Tue 17 April 2018
Wed
Mon 16 April 2018
Tue
Fri 13 April 2018
Mon
Thu 12 April 2018
```

I understand this isn't pretty but i've been looking at it too long and I've become tunnel visioned.  Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: If today is Monday 30th April, what is the expected output?

Comment: Friday 27th April

Comment: I thought Monday was supposed to go to Thursday based on *"So, when I then land on a Tuesday, that needs to go to Friday and the Monday to Thursday"*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note the use of the `sunday?` method to determine if a certain date happens to be a sunday.

```
require "date"
def date_calc_minus(number)
  d = Date.today
  number.times do
    d -= 1
    d -= 2 if d.sunday?
  end
  d
end
```

Comment: That simple!! Thank you

Comment: A very smart solution.

Comment: Nice solution. Alternatively, `number.times { d -= d.monday? ? 3 : 1 }`.

Answer (score 1):

My solution emphasizes efficiency at the expense of simplicity. I assume the start date is a weekday.

```
require 'date'

def lookin_back(start_date, n)
  days_after_monday = start_date.wday - 1
  return start_date - n if n <= days_after_monday
  weeks, days = (n - days_after_monday).divmod(5)
  start_date - days_after_monday - 7*weeks - (days > 0 ? days + 2 : 0) 
end
```

```
start_date = Date.today
  #=> #<Date: 2018-04-30 ((2458239j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
start_date.wday
  #=> 1 (Monday)

lookin_back(start_date, 0)
  #=> #<Date: 2018-04-30 ((2458239j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
lookin_back(start_date, 1)
  #=> #<Date: 2018-04-27 ((2458236j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
lookin_back(start_date, 5)
  #=> #<Date: 2018-04-23 ((2458232j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
lookin_back(start_date, 6)
  #=> #<Date: 2018-04-20 ((2458229j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
lookin_back(start_date, 7)
  #=> #<Date: 2018-04-19 ((2458228j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
lookin_back(start_date, 11)
  #=> #<Date: 2018-04-13 ((2458222j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
lookin_back(start_date, 16)
  #=> #<Date: 2018-04-06 ((2458215j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

```
start_date += 2
  #=> #<Date: 2018-05-02 ((2458241j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
start_date.wday
  #=> 3 (Wednesday)

lookin_back(start_date, 0)
  #=> #<Date: 2018-05-02 ((2458241j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
lookin_back(start_date, 1)
  #=> #<Date: 2018-05-01 ((2458240j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
lookin_back(start_date, 2)
  #=> #<Date: 2018-04-30 ((2458239j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
lookin_back(start_date, 3)
  #=> #<Date: 2018-04-27 ((2458236j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
lookin_back(start_date, 5)
  #=> #<Date: 2018-04-25 ((2458234j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
lookin_back(start_date, 10)
  #=> #<Date: 2018-04-18 ((2458227j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
lookin_back(start_date, 15)
  #=> #<Date: 2018-04-11 ((2458220j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
lookin_back(start_date, 12345)
  #=> #<Date: 1971-01-06 ((2440958j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```